# Load event does not load function dynamicLayout function, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, stylesheet

I'm learning how to use dynamic layouts, and I am using this [example here](http://www.particletree.com/examples/dynamiclayouts/)

This example is supposed to dynamic change stylesheets based on the browser window's resolution on load and during resizing. If decrease the width of my browser window enough, then the css switches to thin.css. But if I refresh or load the page in a small window, the css being used is default.css

I assume that at the time of the author's publication, this code work 100%, but I want to know why it no longer works.

Here is the [javascript](http://www.particletree.com/examples/dynamiclayouts/scripts/dynamiclayout.js).

It looks like

```
addEvent(window, 'resize', dynamicLayout);
```

works, but

```
addEvent(window, 'load', dynamicLayout);
```

does not work. I've tried to tweak the code by using

```
window.onload = dynamicLayout;
```

but that does not work either.

Comment: which browser did you tested?

Comment: Tested on Chrome, Internet Explorer, and FireFox (all up to date and standard versions). It does not work on Chrome or IE, but it works flawlessly on FireFox. The problem stems from browser incompatibilities. Link for more information: http://www.particletree.com/features/dynamic-resolution-dependent-layouts/

Comment: 2005 is a long time ago. There are now much easier ways to do this, such as using Bootstrap's Grid Layout.

Comment: I've heard of Twitter Bootstrap. I'm not sure that's the same thing, and I want to know why it's called Twitter Bootstrap. I haven't learnt it yet, and I'm looking for a good tutorial or explanation of it.

I just started going into Web Design and Dev a week and a half ago, and I don't feel ready working with Web Frameworks. That's why I didn't consider using Bootstrap.